# Proxy error: Could not proxy request /user/update from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So I have a MERN application, and everything works fine. Post, Get, and Delete all work fine but on my React terminal i keep getting an error saying

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /user/update from localhost:3000 to 
http://localhost:5000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information. 
(ECONNRESET).
```

I'm just lost on how my application can work fine, like it adds, deletes, and gets data from my mongoDB server just fine, but this message keeps popping up. I've made some changes to my route in order to try getting it working on heroku, which hasn't been successful as well. However locally, everything seems to work besides that error message I keep getting.

Inside my package.json I have specified

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
```

My server.js is

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");

// Allow to get information from .env file
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const url = process.env.ATLAS_URL;

// Express.static --> charge of sending static files requests to the client
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "public")));

mongoose.connect(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
});

// Checking to see if mongoose connection was successful
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

// Routes
const userRouter = require("./routes/user");

app.use("/user", userRouter);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/public"));
}

// "Catchall" route hander.
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "public", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port: " + port);
});
```

My routes is this

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/user.model");

// Gets users from database
router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
  User.find()
    .then((user) => res.json(user))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});

// Adds a new user to the userDB
router.route("/signup").post((req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const email = req.body.email;

  const newUser = new User({
    username,
    password,
    email,
  });

  newUser
    .save()
    .then(() => res.json("User added to userDB"))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});

// Adds a new todoList for the current user
router.route("/update").post((req, res) => {
  const userId = req.body.id;

  const newTodoList = {
    title: req.body.title,
    content: req.body.content,
  };

  // Finds user and updates the todoList for that user
  const filter = { _id: userId };
  const update = { $push: { todoList: newTodoList } };
  User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update)
    .then(() => res.json("User updated with todoList"))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});

// Gets userId and noteId from parameters and find the current user and deletes the note that wants to be deleted.
router.route("/delete/:userId/:noteId").delete((req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.userId;
  const noteId = req.params.noteId;

  const filter = { _id: userId };
  const update = { $pull: { todoList: { _id: noteId } } };

  User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update)
    .then(() => res.json("Note Deleted"))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

My React client side code looks like this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";

function CreateArea(props) {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);

  const [note, setNote] = useState({
    id: "",
    title: "",
    content: "",
  });

  // Updating hooks when user types
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setNote((prevNote) => {
      return {
        ...prevNote,
        [name]: value,
        id: props.id,
      };
    });
  }

  // Posting note to db
  function submitNote(e) {
    // Clears user's title and content after user clicks submit button
    setNote({
      id: "",
      title: "",
      content: "",
    });
    // Posts user with new todoList
    axios.post("/user/update", note).then((res) => console.log(res.data));
  }

  function expand() {
    setIsExpanded(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="createArea">
        {isExpanded ? (
          <input
            name="title"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={note.title}
            placeholder="Title"
          />
        ) : null}
        <textarea
          name="content"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={note.content}
          placeholder="Take a note..."
          rows="3"
          onClick={expand}
        />
        {isExpanded ? (
          <button onClick={submitNote}>
            <AddIcon />
          </button>
        ) : null}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateArea;
```

Comment: Okay it looks like if i prevent the page from refreshing, the error doesn't show. Problem is i need to refresh the page in order for the new list to be displayed on the dashboard..

Comment: check out this article, it might be helpful, https://medium.com/@bryantjiminson/solving-proxy-error-could-not-proxy-request-xxx-from-yyy-from-local-reactjs-app-to-nodejs-app-f28f3548afb9